# How to delete using ADO.Net Entity Framework

Tags: ado.net-entity-data-model

I am unable to delete a record from the the table using ADO.Net Entity Framework.
Debugging lets me go through the method without any errors.

```
Cust_DataModel.Cust_DataEntities db = new Cust_DataModel.Cust_DataEntities();

protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (lvCust.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        int custId = Convert.ToInt32(lvCust.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());
        var cust = db.Cust.FirstOrDefault(d => d.CustId == custId );

        try
        {
            int co = db. Cust.Count();
            db.AttachTo("Cust", cust);

            db.DeleteObject(cust);
            int co2 = db. Cust.Count();
            db.SaveChanges();
            int co1 = db. Cust.Count();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        lblMessage.Text = "cust was deleted.";
    }
    else
        lblMessage.Text = "No cust was selected.";
}
```

I am able to list the items from the table into a ListView.

```
private void BindCust()
{
  var custs = from cust in db.Cust where cust.UserId == userId orderby cust.Created descending select cust;

            lvCust.DataSource = custs;
            lvCust.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: looks like cust already attached since you get it from db just before deleting... isn't it?

Comment: Even if I remove the attach statement it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but don't you need to save changes after attaching an item before deleting it?